# How to change the HTML5 “md-” prefix in Vue Material?

Tags: vue.js, vue-material

I want to change this **Vue Material** prefix tags "md-":

```html
<md-button>{{title1}}</md-button>
```

to:

```html
<custom-button>{{title1}}</custom-button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the vue-material source code, All the components specify the 'name' attribute manually. You can see an example of that in the [code for MdAutocomplete](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/blob/dev/src/components/MdAutocomplete/MdAutocomplete.vue#L46).

You could change the `name: 'MdAutocomplete',` to `name: 'CustomAutocomplete',` for each of the files.

---

There's also a bit of a messier approach that you could take using Vue's async components system. After doing the normal vue-material setup process:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'

Vue.use(VueMaterial)
```

You can specify custom component aliases like so:

```js
import Vue from "vue"

export default {
  components: {
    CustomButton: () => Promise.resolve(Vue.component('MdButton'))
  },
  // ...
}
```